Query - Same Tables Twice
This is from SAP Business One - Hana database but the concept is the same for SQL.
I have a query that lists all of the invoices and payments in the system.
SELECT T2."TotalExpns" AS "Total Freight",T2."NumAtCard", T6."LineTotal",T7."SlpName", 
'' AS "CardName", T0."ReconNum",T1."SrcObjAbs" AS "DocEntry", T1."SrcObjTyp" AS "Type 
13 Inv 24 Incoming Payment", T2."DocNum", T2."FatherCard", T2."CardCode", 
T1."ReconSum", '' AS "DocDate", '' AS "CheckNo" FROM OITR T0  
INNER JOIN ITR1 T1 ON T0."ReconNum" = T1."ReconNum" 
INNER JOIN OINV T2 ON T1."SrcObjAbs" = T2."DocEntry" 
INNER JOIN INV1 T6 ON T2."DocEntry" = T6."DocEntry"
INNER JOIN OSLP T7 ON T2."SlpCode" = T7."SlpCode"
WHERE T0."ReconNum" ='52837' AND  T0."Canceled" = 'N' AND  T0."IsCard" = 'C' AND 
T1."SrcObjTyp" = '13'

UNION ALL
SELECT 0 AS "Total Freight", '' AS "NumAtCard",0 AS "LineTotal", '' AS "SlpName", 
T4."CardName", T0."ReconNum",T1."SrcObjAbs" AS "DocEntry", T1."SrcObjTyp" AS "Type 13 
Inv 24 Incoming Payment", T2."DocNum", T2."FatherCard", T2."CardCode", T1."ReconSum", 
T3."DocDate", T3."CounterRef" AS "CheckNo" FROM OITR T0  INNER JOIN ITR1 T1 ON 
T0."ReconNum" = T1."ReconNum" INNER JOIN OINV T2 ON T1."SrcObjAbs" = T2."DocEntry"
INNER JOIN ORCT T3 ON T3."DocEntry" = T1."SrcObjAbs"
INNER JOIN OINV T4 ON T2."DocNum" = T4."DocNum"
WHERE T0."ReconNum" ='52837' AND  T0."Canceled" = 'N' AND  T0."IsCard" = 'C'  AND 
T1."SrcObjTyp" = '24'
ORDER BY T0."ReconNum"

The results are in the screen shot, what I need is for type 24 to be on the same line for all of the type 13 records.  The system only puts the document date and check number on line 24
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
If you have this in SQL, I can convert it to Hana


Not sure I understand the requirement. Can you share an example of the result you want to get instead of describing it?

Use a CTE/Subquery instead of union:
;WITH CHECKDATE
AS
(
SELECT 0 AS "Total Freight", '' AS "NumAtCard",0 AS "LineTotal", '' AS "SlpName", 
T4."CardName", T0."ReconNum",T1."SrcObjAbs" AS "DocEntry", T1."SrcObjTyp" AS "Type 13 
Inv 24 Incoming Payment", T2."DocNum", T2."FatherCard", T2."CardCode", T1."ReconSum", 
T3."DocDate", T3."CounterRef" AS "CheckNo" FROM OITR T0  INNER JOIN ITR1 T1 ON 
T0."ReconNum" = T1."ReconNum" INNER JOIN OINV T2 ON T1."SrcObjAbs" = T2."DocEntry"
INNER JOIN ORCT T3 ON T3."DocEntry" = T1."SrcObjAbs"
INNER JOIN OINV T4 ON T2."DocNum" = T4."DocNum"
WHERE T0."ReconNum" ='52837' AND  T0."Canceled" = 'N' AND  T0."IsCard" = 'C'  AND 
T1."SrcObjTyp" = '24'
ORDER BY T0."ReconNum"
)

SELECT T2."TotalExpns" AS "Total Freight",T2."NumAtCard", T6."LineTotal",T7."SlpName", 
'' AS "CardName", T0."ReconNum",T1."SrcObjAbs" AS "DocEntry", T1."SrcObjTyp" AS "Type 
13 Inv 24 Incoming Payment", T2."DocNum", T2."FatherCard", T2."CardCode", 
T1."ReconSum", 
CHECKDATE."DocDate",
CHECKDATE."CheckNo"

FROM OITR T0  
INNER JOIN ITR1 T1 ON T0."ReconNum" = T1."ReconNum" 
INNER JOIN OINV T2 ON T1."SrcObjAbs" = T2."DocEntry" 
INNER JOIN INV1 T6 ON T2."DocEntry" = T6."DocEntry"
INNER JOIN OSLP T7 ON T2."SlpCode" = T7."SlpCode"

LEFT JOIN CHECKDATE ON CHECKDATE."ReconNum" = T0."ReconNum"

WHERE T0."ReconNum" ='52837' AND  T0."Canceled" = 'N' AND  T0."IsCard" = 'C' AND 
T1."SrcObjTyp" = '13'


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
